# Rails app isn't rendering Topic Name, instead renders topics/9

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The view is essentially rendering the topic ID instead of the Topic Name. Here is the code for the topics index view.

```
<h1>Topics</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
    <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
      <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="media-heading">
            <%= link_to topic.name, topic %>
            <h1>Test</h1>
          </h4>
          <small>
            <%= topic.description %>
          </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= will_paginate @topics %>
  </div>
  <div class="span4">

      <%= link_to "New Topic", new_topic_path, class: 'btn btn-large btn-block' %>

  </div>
</div>
<script>
```

I don't think I should need anything like friendly_id to get the name to render properly. I could be wrong.. However I was unable to solve the issue with Friendly_Id. Someone mentioned it could be a routing issue, so here is my routes.

routes.rb

```
Bloccit::Application.routes.draw do

  get "posts/index"

  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'users/registrations' }


  resources :users, only: [:show, :index]
  resources :posts, only: [:index]
  resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index], controller: 'topics/posts' do
      resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
      match '/up-vote', to: 'votes#up_vote', as: :up_vote
      match '/down-vote', to: 'votes#down_vote', as: :down_vote
      resources :favorites, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end


  match "about" => 'welcome#about', via: :get

  root to: 'welcome#index'

end
```

Here is topic.rb

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base

  # has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true

  attr_accessible :description, :name, :public, :topic
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  scope :visible_to, lambda { |user| user ? scoped : where(public: true) }
end
```

Here is topics_controller.rb

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController

  def index
     # @topics = Topic.all
     @topics = Topic.visible_to(current_user).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end


  def new
      @topic = Topic.new
      authorize! :create, @topic, message: "You need to be an admin to do that."
  end

  def show
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
      authorize! :read, @topic, message: "You need to be signed in to do that."
      @posts = @topic.posts.includes(:user).includes(:comments).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end

  def edit
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
      authorize! :update, @topic, message: "You need to be an admin to do that."
  end

  def create
      @topic = Topic.new(params[:id])
      authorize! :create, @topic, message: "You need to be an admin to do that."
        if @topic.save
          redirect_to @topic, notice: "Topic was saved successfully"
        else
          flash[:error] = "Error creating topic. Please try again."
          render :new
        end
  end

  def update
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :update, @topic, message: "You need to own the topic to update it"
    if @topic.update_attributes(params[:topic])
      redirect_to @topic, notice: "Topic was saved successfully."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error saving topic. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    name = @topic.name
    authorize! :destroy, @topic, message: "You need to own the topic to delete it."
    if @topic.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{name}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to topics_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error deleting the topic."
      render :show
    end
  end

end
```

I don't know if this is helpful or not but I have a posts controller that is nested under topics.

topics/posts_controller.rb

```
    class Topics::PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    authorize! :read, @topic, message: "You need to be user to do that."
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.new
    authorize! :create, Post, message: "You need to be a member to share a new source."
  end

  def edit
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :edit, @post, message: "You need to own the post to edit it."
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
    @post.topic = @topic
    authorize! :create, @post, message: "You need to be signed up to do that."
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Post was saved."
      redirect_to [@topic, @post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :update, @post, message: "You need to own the post to edit it."
    if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
      flash[:notice] = "Post was updated."
      redirect_to [@topic, @post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments
    @comment = Comment.new

    title = @post.title
    authorize! :destroy, @post, message: "You need to own the post to delete it."
    if @post.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{title}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to @topic
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error deleting the post."
      render :show
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: is the name appearing correctly ? do you need the route to be `topics/name` ?

Comment: The name is appearing as topics/1 instead of the topic name. I don't think I shouldn't need a gem to get it to display correctly. I added my routes up above..

Comment: I mean you want the name to act as an id, so instead of topics/id it becomes topics/name ?

Comment: Not sure.. So when I create a topic in the browser with a name and description, the topic is saved correctly. Than I go to the rails console and find the topic I just created, it shows 'nil' for name and description... is this a controller issue?? (using rails version 3.2)

Comment: show your controller, and model (related parts)

Comment: I believe that should be all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `create` action in `topics_controller.rb`, you use `params[:id]` which should be the `params[:topic]` :

```
def create
  @topic = Topic.new(params[:topic])
  authorize! :create, @topic, message: "You need to be an admin to do that."
  if @topic.save
    redirect_to @topic, notice: "Topic was saved successfully"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Error creating topic. Please try again."
    render :new
  end
end
```